# How do I make a new list of strings from another list based on certain criteria?

Tags: c#, algorithm

That's the best way I could think to ask the question, the detail is below.  It's taken me an hour just to figure out how to ask the question!

Let's say that I have 5 (or more) types of text files - they are generated by a scientific instrument and each has certain results.  Let's call these "types" A, B, C, D, E. The actual names of the text files don't give this away so the user can't easily see what they are just by the name.  If it makes it easier, we could just consider a list of "strings". { I have NO idea what to do about replcate types but I'll worry about that later)

I wish to give the user the option to combine the text files into a conglomerate file but the challenge is, it doesn't make sense to combine certain types (for reasons that I don't feel it worthwhile to go into).

I've constructed and example matrix of compatibility

```
        A   B   C   D   E
   A    1   1   1   1   0
   B    1   1   1   0   0
   C    1   1   1   1   0
   D    1   0   1   1   1
   E    0   0   0   1   1
```

So, this is saying that I could combine A with B, C, D but not E (and so on).

Now if a user chooses files that have types  "A, B and C" from a list of files (that aren't obviously typed) I would like to check the selections and say "yes, ABC is a legal merge" and perform the merge.

If the user selects A,B,C,D, I would like to say, NO, you can't do that as D is not compatible with B - however, you could do A,B,C or A,C,D (as D should not be where B would be).

Still with me?

I created the above matrix in code and have got to a looping structure where I started to get a bit muddled and thought I might ask for some help before I find myself losing my home and family.  I've got a fairly large comment section on how I'm trying to make choices.  Remember that "A" could be "Dog" and "B" could be "Cat" etc.

```
internal class CompatibilityCheck
{
    private List<string> FileTypes;

    public CompatibilityCheck()
    {
        //Strings are unique types for text files
        FileTypes = new List<string> {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
        int[,] CompatibilityMatrix =
            {
                {1, 1, 1, 1, 0},
                {1, 1, 1, 0, 0},
                {1, 1, 1, 1, 0},
                {1, 0, 1, 1, 1},
                {0, 0, 0, 1, 1}
            };

        /* Scenario 1 */
        //List of file names from user = ALL LEGAL
        var userSelection = new List<string> {"A", "B", "C"};
        /* Go through each item in userSelection and make arrays of "legal" file combinations?
         * start with A and find the compatible matches, B and C.  Check that B and C are okay. 
        * Answer should look like this as A, B and C can be combined */

        /* Scenario 2 */
        // List of file names from user = NOT ALL LEGAL => D and B are incompatible
        var userSelection2 = new List<string> {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
        /* In my head, I go through each item in userSelction2
         * Take A and build "A,B,C,D" as it is compatible
         *  check B with C(yes) and D(no) - remove D.
         *      end [ A,B,C ]
         *          
         * Start with B and build B,A,C
         *  check A with C(yes) 
         *      end [ B,A,C ]
         *          
         * Start with C and build C,A,B
         *  check A with B(yes)
         *      end [C,A,B]
         *      
         * Start with D and build D,A,C
         *  check A with C(yes)
         *      end [D,A,C]
         *      
         * take the nth string and compare to n+1, n+2 ... n+(length-n)
         *  
         * the unique string sets woudld be  A , B , C and A , C , D  
         */
    }
}
```

I hope this is clear.  So What is the best way to achieve such a task?  Recursion, LINQ "Magic", matrix math?

[EDIT:] An idea I just had that may be easier to implement, might be to Show a list of files and as a user selects them, I could "deactivate" the other choices that aren't compatible.  Imagine a listBox or similar where you select an "A" type and if the above matrix is in play, type "E" files would be greyed out.  I wonder if this will cause me less stress ...?

Comment: Is your question "how do I detect incompatibility" or "how do I give to user something she did not ask, because she asked for impossible result"? If it's the second then I would present a problem to the user, provide her with options, and let her choose.

Comment: @Dialecticus I guess it's more "if incompatibility is detected, give the user the other 'legal' options".  I can handle the presentation of the "new" options and the logic behind that, it's more the logic of how to get the 'legal' combinations that I'm struggling with.

Comment: +1 for spending a time to formulate a good answer

Comment: Can there be input like `A,A,B,C,D,D` (multiple of the same type) ?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is a possibility - I made the comment that I wouldn't know what to do with it - I should test the code from @Belogix and see if it copes with this.

Comment: @AndersH The selected answer takes care of multple entries of same type.

Comment: You say you have "5 or more" file types, but is this only to illustrate the problem, or is this also true for the real situation? If not, how many file types are there (roughly)? In general, for smaller numbers you can get away with less complex algorithms.

Comment: @Astrotrain - in my actual problem I think there may be 5 or 6.  It is not inconceivable that a 7th type may come along so I was trying to build a method with this flexibility included for future-proofing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't had much time to look at this or refactor my code so this is more of a brain dump but might be a good place to start and refactor into something a little neater!

```
public class StrongFileType
{
    private string _friendlyName = string.Empty;

    public StrongFileType(string friendlyName)
    {
        _friendlyName = friendlyName;
    }

    public IEnumerable<StrongFileType> CompatibleTypes { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _friendlyName;
    }
}

private void SampleTest()
{
    // The possible types
    var typeA = new StrongFileType("A");
    var typeB = new StrongFileType("B");
    var typeC = new StrongFileType("C");
    var typeD = new StrongFileType("D");
    var typeE = new StrongFileType("E");

    // Setup possible compatible types
    typeA.CompatibleTypes = new List<StrongFileType> { typeA, typeB, typeC, typeD };
    typeB.CompatibleTypes = new List<StrongFileType> { typeA, typeB, typeC };
    typeC.CompatibleTypes = new List<StrongFileType> { typeA, typeB, typeC, typeD };
    typeD.CompatibleTypes = new List<StrongFileType> { typeA, typeC, typeD, typeE };
    typeE.CompatibleTypes = new List<StrongFileType> { typeD, typeE };

    // Now do a check...
    var userSubmittedFilesValid = new List<StrongFileType> { typeA, typeB, typeC };
    CheckCompatible(userSubmittedFilesValid);
    var userSubmittedFilesInvalid = new List<StrongFileType> { typeA, typeB, typeC, typeD };
    CheckCompatible(userSubmittedFilesInvalid);
}

private bool CheckCompatible(IEnumerable<StrongFileType> requestedFiles)
{
    // Useful for debugging
    var validList = new List<string>();
    var invalidList = new List<string>();

    foreach (StrongFileType fileType in requestedFiles)
    {
        string invalid = string.Empty;
        string validCombination = string.Empty;

        foreach (StrongFileType fileTypeToCheck in requestedFiles)
        {
            if (!fileType.CompatibleTypes.Contains(fileTypeToCheck))
            {
                // Show as not compatible and remove any previously valid combinations that match
                invalid += string.Format("{0} not compatible with {1}", fileType, fileTypeToCheck);
                validList.RemoveAll(x => x.Contains(fileType.ToString()) && x.Contains(fileTypeToCheck.ToString()));
            }
            else
            {
                validCombination += string.Format("{0}", fileTypeToCheck);
            }
        }

        // Add to respective lists
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(validCombination) && !validList.Contains(validCombination))
        {
            validList.Add(validCombination);
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(invalid))
        {
            invalidList.Add(invalid);
        }
    }

    // Was valid?
    return invalidList.Count == 0;
}
```

This should result with the first one showing VALID list of ABC and INVALID list is empty. Second one should show ABC and ACD as VALID and BD and DB as INVALID.

Sorry I didn't have more time to tidy it up!

Comment: I should add that the lists contain strings but this could just as easily be list of StrongFileType etc. Just added them for debugging so you could see a simple output of what you were getting. You can also remove a lot of the string.format etc and generally tidy up! Did it in my lunch break so didn't have time to clean it up! Also, you may want to return the list of valid lists rather than boolean. Hope it helps!

Comment: I think you had a very productive lunch @Belogix !  I've compiled it and tested - seems good!!  I've got a bit more playing but looks very good at this stage!

Comment: I tested it again, expanded the types to go to "F" and added multiples of the same type - all was good.  Many,many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at a [clique problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem) - specifically the *maximum* clique problem.

There are [algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bron%E2%80%93Kerbosch_algorithm) you can use to solve this, but none yet that are better than exponential-time.

Your edit sounds like a much better idea - it should be easier to restrict the choices as you go along.

Comment: `it's an exponential time problem` - probably, but we are not sure ([P=NP Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem)). The correct terminology is NP-Hard, or NP-Complete, and the fact is - there is no *known* polynomial time algorithm for this problem

Comment: oh, that's rather depressing ... but at least @Rawling was able to give my pain a nice name! If my options are limited to less than 6 it seems like it could be done by brute force.

Comment: Yes, now that I search for "Clique" in SO they do seem to be rather problematic.  Might see how far the answer from @Belogix can take me ...